How to get name of the script used in a job on Cloudera ML platform
I want to programmatically retrieve the name of the script used in the current job that runs a python script on the Cloudera ML platform.

__file__ magic variable doesn't work as in the background our Cloudera runtime uses ipython to execute the script
I could get the script associated with the specific job via an API call retrieving meta-information about the job, but I fail to find the job id in the environmental variables

What could I try else?

Could you try?
import sys
sys.argv[0]

or
import inspect
source_file_path = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())

or
print(os.getenv('JPY_SESSION_NAME'))

or
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

print(args, unknown)


nope: the first points at ipykernel_launcher.py (the launcher of jobs in the Cloudera platform) the second at a temporary file: /tmp/ipykernel_12/1234567890.py (the numbers are random here)

and this one:
pip install lib-programname
import lib_programname
this returns the fully resolved path to the launched python program
path_to_program = lib_programname.get_path_executed_script()  # type: pathlib.Path

also ipykernel_launcher.py :(

And this one: print(os.getenv('JPY_SESSION_NAME'))

not defined: None

No idea, sorry. Pheharps could you inject the name of the file in some docstring and  read it on runtime... But is far way from what do you want.

Could you try one mor thing:
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

print(args, unknown)


Namespace() ['-f', '/tmp/jupyter/runtime/kernel-1234567890.json'] and the mentioned json doesn't contain any relevant info

Based on all tries, I dont know :(

I hope my message finds you well.
I have several ideas:
first idea ,  you should check environment variables. you should look for keys related to  "CML," "CLOUDERA," "JOB," or something like that.
enter code here
 import os
 for key, value in os.environ.items():
  print(f"{key}: {value}")

second idea,
You can also use Cloudera ML SDK. Cloudera generally has SDK to communicate with their Ml. f available, you can use the SDK to retrieve job metadata, including the script name. For example,
enter code here
  from cmlbootstrap import CMLBootstrap
  cml = CMLBootstrap()  
  job_info = cml.get_job()
  print(job_info)

Third idea,
Access Metadata via API
If you couldn't access to job ID directly, you can make API calls to retrieve metadata. I mean, use the Cloudera ML API to list active jobs and filter by user or creation time.
Moreover, you can pass the job ID or script name as an argument or environment variable when configuring the job in Cloudera ML. For instance, add a parameter to the job definition in Cloudera ML.
Use sys.argv or os.environ to retrieve it in the script.
enter code here
job_id = os.getenv("JOB_ID")
print(f"Running job with ID: {job_id}")

Furthermore, you are able to use Retrieve Notebook Metadata. which means, Since Cloudera uses Jupyter or IPython under the hood, you might be able to retrieve the notebook's metadata if applicable.
Thanks

1). I've checked it as one of the first things. There no environmental variable storing relevant information.
2). cmlbootstrap seems to be an unofficial and unsupported CML API wrapper: https://github.com/fastforwardlabs/cmlbootstrap/. Moreover, it doesn't seem to have the get_job method. The official cmlapi package, as linked on that github page, has more up-to-date API implementation, but also requires job id.
3). Using environmental variables to set the job id is not a solution as otherwise I could have set the script name as the enviornmental variable at the first place.
